# Is it dangerous to install my work's 802.1x certificate?

Tags: certificates, man-in-the-middle, 802.1x

My employer, the University of Texas at Austin (UT), requires devices running some operating systems* to accept a certificate before they connect. Information about the certificate is available here:

https://management.pna.utexas.edu/howto/

After I accepted the certificate on my iPhone, I looked at the certificate settings (Settings > General > About) and didn't see any certificates listed, and I wasn't required to enter my iPhone's password, so I don't *think* I installed a root certificate.
My questions are:

- Did I do anything other than trust that the WiFi network that I connected to is official University of Texas at Austin WiFi?
- Will the UT network be able to perform Man in the Middle attacks on HTTPS/SSL encrypted sites without setting off an "Invalid Certificate" warning**?
- Are there any other services (perhaps VPNs) that the UT network could spoof without setting off a certificate warning?

*So far, my iPhone requires me to accept the certificate but my Chromebook does not.

**They could perform a MitM attack on HTTP sites, but that's true to any WiFi network regardless of whether I accept a certificate.

Comment: 1. No. 2. No. 3. Err, yes, e.g. an unencrypted service like DNS or HTTP won't show you a certificate warning. Guess this is not what you're really asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely not a Root CA since the website specifically says :

> Verify that the certificate is for dot1x.utexas.edu and lists GeoTrust CA as the issuer.

The certificate purpose is to be used for the radius authentication for the wireless network of the university (more on [Apple radius certificate](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207866))

Not being a root CA, they cannot MitM any https website provided you don't ignore security warning messages.